# layout_marginRight in RelativeLayout works on Android 17, but not on 22

Tags: android

My Layout works fine on Android 17, but not on Android 22. The long message should have a margin of 50dp to the right.

Android 17:

[image]

Android 22:

[image]

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bubble_new"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_message_item_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_message_item_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/list_message_item_username"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do that margin in RelativeLayout not in TextView

I hope this would be help you.

Comment: This works for both versions. Will this have any drawbacks than using it on the `TextView`?

Comment: no, this not drawback but your bubble should be in RelativeLayout so that code put in there

Answer (score 0):

Use :
`layout_marginEnd` for API above 21
and
`layout_marginRight` for API below 21

Comment: try adding both with same values for margin

Answer (score 0):

please use this code for both api level its working fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
android:background="@drawable/bubble_new"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_message_item_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_message_item_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/list_message_item_username"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="17sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```